# Sails js migration every time update my firebase collection index with safe and alter option

Tags: firebase, sails.js, waterline

I am using [Waterline Firebase Adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-firebase) for my sails application. I have create a collection user and insert one manually object name in it, when I again push sails lift command with migration option 1 then it will remove my new index.

[image]

After sails lift the data look like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are in development mode. You need to specify custom indexes in the User model within Sails, or it will remove them when lifting the server and performing migration.

Another solution (also my preferred one) is to manage all indexes on your own within the DB. In order to do so, you have to change the "migrate" attribute from "alter" to "safe" in models.js config file.

Note that in production mode "migrate" attribute is always set to "safe".

Further info [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings) in the migration section.